OBS Won't Record Game at 1080p, Shrinks Screen When Resolution Increased
OBS won't record my game at 1080p, only at 720p. Increasing the resolution in OBS settings shrinks the screen. I've adjusted the game resolution too, but it's not working. Any solutions??

I’m voting to close this question because this is a software support question.  The problem you've described is external to the game development process because the game dev process doesn't make or break OBS support. The fact that you're using it for playtesting is coincidental and there's no clear reason why it should be directed to game developers.

There is a discord dedicated to obs, they will be able to provide better help with your problem

The question would benefit from a lot more detail. For example: Does other recoding software work correctly with your game? Does OBS work correctly with other games? What technologies (e.g. OpenGL,, D3D 11, Unity) are you using to make your game? What operating system is it running on? What CPU and GPU are you using?
